# In graph algorithm, if vertex average degree is two, which one is the better to use, adjacency matrix or adjacency list?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I want to know which one is better and why if vertex has two edges each. Sorry for very simple question, but I searched a lot.. and cannot understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends on your criteria for judging "better" and on what graph operations you want to support. For a graph with 2n edges, though, an adjacency list will be much more space-efficient than the sparse adjacency matrix (which will have n^2 - 2n zero entries).

Comment: As @chepner said. Another consideration is that if there are only two entries in each node's adjacency list, you can always search out-edges quickly. When out-degree k can be very large, adjacency lists need to be kept as efficient maps (e.g. hashmaps) to avoid O(k) lookup times.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate more on the comments of @chepner and @Gene, you need to consider the operations you are going to apply on the graph. Another issue, there are two types of edge lists: Global edge list and Local edge list. For example, finding all edges in the graph takes O(m) for the global and local edge list and O(n^2) for the adjacency matrix where m is the number of edges and n is the number of nodes. Another example is to find the neighbors of a node v, for the global edge list it takes O(m) and for the local edge list it takes O(deg(v)) and for adjacency matrix is O(n).